# Message receive observers doesn't work after unsubscribing from channels

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I'm checking for incoming messages in my `AppDelegate.m`, `RootViewController.m` and `ViewControllerB.m` .

After the user opens the app (first launch - install), signs up then logs in, everything works correctly. 5 seconds or 50 min later (it doesn't matter) the current user logs out and comes a new user who creates a new account or signing in with an existing profile. Now, current user sends a message (successfully) to his own channel, but this time the message observers doesn't work, no logs from the observers. However if I shut down the app from Xcode and launch it again it works correctly again.

I'm sure it's not a network issue, because the history contains every message, that I sent and the client connects every each time. But unfortunately the message receive observers like they wouldn't exist.

I suspect the trouble happens when the user logs out and unsubscribes from the channels he listening. I've tried it with and without `removeMessageReceiveObserver:`, but doesn't helped me out.

This is how I tear down the subscriptions when the user logs out:

```
 if (cell == staticCell ) {
   ...
    NSArray *unsubscribe = @[channel1, channel2];
    //unsubscribe user from channels
    [PubNub unsubscribeFromChannels:unsubscribe];
    // remove observer and disconnect from PubNub.
    [[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] removeMessageReceiveObserver:self];
    [PubNub disconnect]; // also tried without closing the connection

    //log out user
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self presentLoginViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And here's my observers:

```
// I'm using this in RootViewController.m and ViewControllerB.m
[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:self withBlock:^(PNMessage *message) {

        if ([message.channel.name isEqualToString:my_channel] ) { 
             NSLog(@" message: %@ ", message.message);
}


// AppDelegate.m

- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessage *)message {

if ([message.channel.name isEqualToString:my_channel] ) {

  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New message"
                                                        message: messageContent delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok!"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];

}
```

Did I missed something? Is there any other methods that I should implement before I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 1):

You should be subscribed on channels from which you want to receive messages. Observer won't inform about messages, if client doesn't see them, because you unsubscribed from them.
**PubNub** client will inform about new messages on channels on which you subscribed, if there is no channels, then there will be no events.

Comment: I subscribe to the new channel after the previous user logged out. But it's interesting, after your answer I tested an another scenario. UserA logs out, UserB logs in - doesn't work - then userB logs out and logs in again right after he logged out and it works again. Possibly is there any minimum time between the observers can change their "target" channels?

Comment: When you switch between users, I think view controller with chat is deallocated, so you should use this `[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] removeMessageReceiveObserver:self]` to remove it as observer. Every time when you open view controller and want it to receive notifications as for new messages, you need to add observer for this kind of event.

Comment: I've put it into my view controllers `viewWillDisappear` method, but still the same. However I couldn't do anything with `pubnubClient: didReceiveMessage:` from the `AppDelegate`, maybe that's the problem. I also tried to utilize the `resetCenter` method, but couldn't call `[PNObservationCenter resetCenter]` because it's protected. Is it possible somehow? Destroying all observers with one call would be an amazing solution.

Comment: @vv88 I suggest you to contact with PubNub via support@pubnub.com where you will be able to share code and we will help you what exactly is wrong or misused.